# Custom Cloudwatch Metric disappears

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I created custom metrics that basically check Mongo replication, connection count, query response time, and connection percentage against maximum allowable connections. The script runs on a 5 minute cron. I have configured the widget to check for these metrics on 5 minute periods. But after a while the the metrics completely disappear off the widget and i have to re add it.

I tried looking this up online but can't find ANY reason why this would happen. I checked on the servers that it's monitoring and I don't find anything in logs that show the cron erroring out. Can any AWS experts tell me where to start troubleshooting this? I'm not expecting to get this resolved with the limited amount of information other than the symptoms of the problem, but is there a way of getting more information on the metrics disappearing via AWS (whether it be CloudTrail or by other means)?

Comment: Are you talking about Amazon CloudWatch Dashboard widgets? If you look at the metrics in the normal CloudWatch console (not on a Dashboard), does the metric data appear? Make sure you have a wider timeframe (eg past 24 hours).

Comment: Hrmm ok, i am talking about the Cloudwatch Widgets. Where would i check to see what the current timeframe is when adding the metric to the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

First things is to confirm that your metrics are available. In the Amazon CloudWatch console, click **Browse Metrics**, then drill-down to find your metric and tick the box.

If the metrics are showing, then the data is there -- it's just a matter of fixing the dashboard widget.

Go to your dashboard widget, click the three dots and select **Edit**. Select a time range in the top-right (1h, 3h, 12h...), then click **Update widget**.

Comment: I was checking back on this. I noticed that I have always kept the time at 1d. Why would metrics disappear if the time is for 1d?

Comment: Are your metrics available in CloudWatch (before looking a them in a widget)? That's the first thing to confirm.

Comment: No. The metrics disappear and I have readd em back to the widget after a certain amount of time... The namespace and widget are created and all, just goes away and i have to readd em

Comment: I'm not talking about the Dashboard or the Widget. If you click Metrics in the left navigation of the CloudWatch console, can you navigate to the actual metrics? You need to make sure the metrics are available in CloudWatch itself before worrying about the Dashboard/Widget.

Comment: Yes they are there in Metrics. Sorry for the late response

Comment: In that case, the metrics are still available in CloudWatch itself. You just have to play with the Dashboard/widget settings to have them visualized.